# ssh connection refused headless install

Tags: system-installation, ssh, raspberrypi, connection

I am trying to do a headless install of ubuntu 20.04 on my raspberry pi 4, however when I try to connect to the Pi via SSH I get the error message "Connection refused".
I have tried copying over a blank ssh file into the boot media but that did not help.

`OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5 debug1: Connecting to 192.168.50.72 [192.168.50.72] port 22. debug1: connect to address 192.168.50.72 port 22: Connection refused ssh: connect to host 192.168.50.72 port 22: Connection refused`

Comment: I assume a typo there is no 20.03

Comment: yes my mistake.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show `ssh -v ...`.

Comment: I hope that is what you where asking for.

Comment: Ubuntu for Raspberry has ssh enabled out-of-the-box, no need to put a blank file on boot partition. First boot of Ubuntu may require 10m to achieve. Check that you are referring to correct ip with `nmap -sn 192.168.50.0/24`

Comment: I can confirm that ubuntu has had adequate to boot up and that I am referring to the correct IP, yet I am still getting the same "connection refused" error.